# openpyxl rgb code format?

Tags: html, colors, openpyxl, color-codes

I have an excel cell which shows the rgb code "FF FF FF 00" (notice the length: it's 8, not 6). When I enter that code on a HTML color picker, I see a different color than inside the excel file. When I put "FF FF 00" instead, I see the right color. Why does openpyxl prefix the HTML color code with "FF"?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space

I was confused because I had found a link earlier where someone said that the last 2 digits indicate the alpha. That didn't seem to apply to my problem. Now I know that there are competing formats, some put the alpha first (aRGB vs RGBa).